# Using UTF8 with ini4j

Tags: java, utf-8, escaping, ini4j

I'm trying to save a .ini-File with all my tab Data from my tabbedPane, I already managed to do so. But since those Tabs could include UTF-8 characters, I want the File to be saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

While I have no problems reading the UTF-8 .ini-File:

```
InputStreamReader reader = null;
reader = new InputStreamReader(
new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
ini.load(reader);
```

As soon as I want to save the edited data it saves it as ANSI and converts the non-ANSI Characters in \uXXXX (X = number):

```
OutputStreamWriter writer  = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
ini.store(writer);
```

Although it is not really bad for reading, since it's shown correctly in my TabbedPane.
It's bad for manually editing, **so I'd like to save my file as UTF8 without BOM without these escaped \uXXXX characters.**

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `ini.store()` method is doing that, it is not happening in the code you have shown.

Comment: Is there any way to surpress this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know this library, but after checking the docu there seems to be a way: you can use `setConfig` with a configuration that has escape set to false. See http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/ini4j/Ini.html#setConfig(org.ini4j.Config)

Comment: Aaah, thanks I missed that.

Comment: I just tested it now, and it's working perfectly, thank you for mentioning that, Henry! Please add your answer, so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Ini` class has a method `setConfig` that can be used to customize the behavior.

In particular, a `Config` that has the `escape` property set to false will suppress the escaping of non-ascii characters.